# mysql slow performance on a small table with join query

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I have a couple of tables that i join together when i execute the following query:

```
SELECT article.year, authors.last_name, count(DISTINCT article.id) as count FROM
article LEFT JOIN authors ON article.id = authors.id WHERE authors.last_name =
'bloggs' GROUP BY article.year
```

For some reason, this is taking between 6 and 7 seconds to return the results which seems unbelievably slow to me given the relatively small number of rows it has to deal with. Am I doing something wrong here?

If I run an EXPLAIN on the query I get the following:

```
select_type    table    type   possible_keys  key    key_len    ref    rows    extra
=====================================================================================
simple         article  all    null           null    null      null   762     using temporary; using filesort
simple         authors  all    null           null    null      null   5061    using where; using join buffer
```

Both tables are InnoDB. I'm running this from my local machine which is fairly low spec (windows xp, 1 ghz, 1gb ram) but even so, I would have thought this would be quicker. If I load a few more rows into the tables it starts to take minutes rather than seconds.

Any thoughts?

Table structures below:

```
Article:

field    type       null    key    default    extra
=======================================================
id       int        yes            null
year     char(20)   yes            null
volume   char(20)   yes            null
issue    char(20)   yes            null
title    text       yes            null

Authors:

field      type       null    key    default    extra
=======================================================
id         int        yes            null
last_name  char(100)  yes            null
initials   char(10)   yes            null
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `authors.last_name`? Do you have indexes on the columns used for the Joins? Do you have index on `authors.last_name`? If you have no indexes at all, it will be slower and slower as the tables grow in size.

Comment: Post yout tables structure as well. (I meant `authors.last_name` and `article.year`.)

Comment: No, currently I do not have any indexes on the columns being used in the query, good point. I hadn't added them as it seemed like a fairly small table to deal with at this stage, but I'll try adding indexes on the affected columns and see if it solves anything...

Comment: You should also consider making `year` an `INT` instead of `char(20)`. It's 4 bytes (or 2 if you make it `SMALLINT`) instead of 20. Less space, less space for the indexes and noone can add a row with `year='my gosh, 2012'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding indexes on columns `authors.last_name` and `authors.id`.

But, are you sure your query is ok? shouldn't it look like :

```
SELECT article.year, authors.last_name, count(DISTINCT article.id) as count FROM
article LEFT JOIN authors ON article.author_id = authors.id WHERE authors.last_name =
'bloggs' GROUP BY article.year
```

If so, an index on `articles.author_id` would be required - although, not for this query, but as a general best practice

Comment: As @Tudor mentions, you need an `article.author_id` field which would be a `FOREIGN KEY` to `author(id)`. You also need to declare which field is the `PRIMARY KEY` (in both tables), and further indexes on any more fields that are used in `WHERE` or `ON`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll have a play and let you know the results.

Comment: Just to let you all know that I added indexes on the relevant columns and it made a massive difference, so thanks for that. Feel a bit silly for not having done it in the first place, I just wasn't expecting it to be so important on such a small table.

Answer (score 0):

As Tudor said, add indexes. You can also extract the group by.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT article.year, authors.last_name, count(DISTINCT article.id) as count FROM
article LEFT JOIN authors ON article.author_id = authors.id WHERE authors.last_name =
'bloggs') GROUP BY article.year
```

Doing this you are first fetching by the join, and in the set, applying the aggregate function.

And `explain` to see  where is the spot to   the improvement.

Font of the suggestion:

http://kccoder.com/mysql/join-group-by-performance/

Comment: Why do you think this change would help?

Comment: You link's example has only one table - and the `GROUP BY` - inside the subquey and the `JOIN` in the exterior query. You have it reversed.